# Batch file to delete subfolders in directory if all files is older than 3 days

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

I need to complete my batch script.
I have a path C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Shaban. In that path there a several subfolders, eg. Ansys. 
In the subfolder Ansys there are even more subfolders = its a foldertree.
My batch script needs to delete the Ansys folder if every files in the folder and the subfolders is older than 3 days. If just one file in Ansyn is modified in the last 3 days then nothing should happen with Ansys. 
I tried to make a solid solution but: 
The batch file deletes a subsubfolder in Ansys directory because the files in the subsubfolder is not modified since 3 days.

I got 3 batch files doing the task.

**Script.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
pushd C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Desktop\Shaban

set /p check="Select a date:" 
Rem When prompted with above line type the date 3 days ago.

forfiles /c "cmd /c (IF @isdir==TRUE call C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Desktop\Search.bat "@path" "%check%")"

popd
```

**Search.bat**

```
set del=TRUE
forfiles /p %1 /d -%2 /s /m * /c "cmd /c (IF @isdir ==TRUE call C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Desktop\DeleteFolders.bat "@path" "%check%" "%del%")"
```

**DeleteFolders.bat**

```
set del=FALSE
if %del%==FALSE (rmdir /S /Q %1)
```

The problem is:
I got a subsubfolder (e.g. hello) in the folder Ansys. In the hello folder every file is older than 3 days. The script deletes the hello folder which it should not do. It should only delete Ansys if EVERY file in the folder is older than 3 days. If just one file is modified in Ansys folder for the past 3 days nothing in the Ansys folder should be deleted.

I made the batch file so it deletes the Ansys folder if every file is older than 3 days. But it should not delete a subsubfolder just because the files in it is older than 3 days.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution can be made much simpler ;)

You can detect if FORFILES printed any result, and take action if nothing was printed.

Use FOR /D to iterate the direct child folders. For each folder, run FORFILES looking for files that are at or later than the cutoff date. If you didn't have to worry about ignoring folders, then you could simply take action based on the FORFILES return code. But you don't want to get a false positive based on a new but empty folder. You can detect if FORFILES printed any filenames using FINDSTR, and delete the folder tree if none were printed. FORFILES still prints an empty line if it finds a new folder, so you must search for a character using `.` instead of searching for a line using `"^"`.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "root=C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Shaban"
set /p "cutoff=Enter a cutoff date (mm/dd/yyyy): "
for /d %%F in ("%root%\*") do (
  2>nul forfiles /p "%%F" /d %cutoff% /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @file"
) | >nul 2>nul findstr . || rd /s /q "%%F"
```

There are multiple methods posted on StackOverflow and elsewhere showing how to do date arithmetic in batch. I'm partial to a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called `getTimestamp.bat`](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847&p=27422). It is pure script that runs on any modern Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party executable required. It is chock full of options, allowing you to do nearly any date computation you could ever imagine.

Assuming `getTimestamp.bat` is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH, then the following line can be used to compute your cutoff date instead of prompting for the date:

```
call gettimestamp -OD -3 -F {mm}/{dd}/{yyyy} -R cutoff
```

Comment: Thanks A lot!!!
I have one more request if you can help me? 

Instead of deleting folders older than a date I need to delete folder older than a hour (e.g. 72 hours). So files older than 72 hours needs to be deleted. And I am running the script through Task Scheduler where I need to set 72 hours as an input parameter for the script as well. Can you help me furthermore?

Comment: Folders need to be deleted if all files in it is older than 72 hours, that's what I meant! :D @dbenham

Comment: @user2439427 - Ouch. Sub day timestamp thresholds are much more difficult, especially if you want the solution to work anywhere in the world. Somewhere I've posted a solution using WMIC that works really well. I'll see if I can find it. But I'm not sure if the WMIC approach will work well with directory trees. I know it can work, but the performance may be terrible. You might want to ask a new question with the new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a VBS script to calculate the date 3 days ago, and then checks if any files are younger than that, using xcopy, and if no files are younger than 3 days then it should remove the `"C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Shaban\Ansys"` folder and subdirectories.

3 days is a date calculation and not exactly 72 hours.

It's not tested.

```
@echo off
call :date today -3
echo mm-dd-yyyy 3 days ago was: %day%

xcopy "C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Shaban\Ansys\*.*" "%temp%\" /l /s /d:%day% |find ":" >nul

if %errorlevel% EQU 1 rd /s /q "C:\Users\Mahmo03S\Shaban\Ansys"

goto :EOF
:date
set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%"&set "MM=%result:~4,2%"&set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "day=%MM%-%DD%-%YY%"
```